# Execute a function when a series of jquery ajax calls complete(!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make a series (1-20) ajax calls and I need to have another function be called when they are all complete. And by complete I mean when $.ajax({ complete: ...}) gets called.

Iv looked into using $.when, but after fiddling with it on jsfiddle I have 2 issues with it. 1. $.then and $.done gets called before all my complete callbacks. 
2. if one single ajax call fails, it wont get called at all.
basically, it seems $.done is called on success, and not complete.

Im thinking there must be some good ajax manager/queue thingy out there that can handle this kind of stuff. Or maybe even some generic async task hanlding thingy.. ;)

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvSgX/2

Comment: You won't find that deferred manager in jQuery...

Comment: Did you take a look here:
 http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2011/10/20/coordinating-multiple-ajax-requests-with-jquery-when/

Comment: @eric.itzhak not that post specifically, but yes. and in the example on that post the whole thing will fail if a single getTweets fails.

Comment: Could you post a link to your jsfiddle in the question?

Comment: @Jim sorry for the delay, but my computer crashed and I forgot to save the original fiddle, but here's a rewrite: http://jsfiddle.net/zvSgX/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like the default jQuery choices for when `$.ajax`
calls resolve their deferred objects, you could write your own wrapper;

```
var my_ajax = function (options) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var user_complete = options.complete;

    options.complete = function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (user_complete) user_complete(jqXHR, textStatus);
        deferred.resolve();
    };

    $.ajax(options);

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Here is a [fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goggin13/zvSgX/5/) which demos it in action with your
sample code.

Since `my_ajax` does not ever call `deferred.reject()`, chaining a `.fail` to `$.when` 
will be meaningless if all the arguments to `$.when` are `my_ajax` calls.

Hope that is helpful! Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use promise pattern to solve this problem
You can use when.js library to resolve this type of problem 
Tutorial and samples are available at below location

https://github.com/cujojs/when

Comment: thanks for pointing me in that direction, but can you please provide an example how this could help me?

Comment: after reading alot of primises and deffered to wrap my head around that pattern, I came up with this as an alternative that uses when.js. but the thing is, its very similar to goggin13's suggestion, so now I wonder what the pro's and con's are.. http://jsfiddle.net/zvSgX/8/

Answer (score 0):

a solution I used recently worked not bad imo. Going through a for-loop I called a method which in turn did a window.setTimeout with a function executing an ajax call with the right data. I used a max and counter variable to check if all ajax calls where executed right (increment counter at the end of the success function). A function called by another setTimeout checked if the counter was equal to max. If not, call the method again in a new setTimeout, otherwise call the function that must be executed at the end.

So in code:

```
var count = 0, max = 0;

function batchCall() {
var a = [{
    method: "DoThis",
    params: { param1: 1, param2: 2 }
}, {
    method: "DoThat",
    params: { param1: 3 }
}]

max = a.length;

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    callAjax(a[i]);
}

window.setTimeout(checkAllFinished, 100);
}

function callAjax(o) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // do ajax call here 
    }, 0);
}

function checkAllFinished() {
    if (count == max) {
        // do what you need to do when all are called
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(checkAllFinished, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: A solution using setTimout is obviously not a solution.